# Access to the path 'XXX' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filepath, directory-permissions

I make a web application and I use a `File Upload server control`. When I save the files to a specific folder, I get `Access denied` to this path all the time also I give `Full control` permission for `Every One`. I work in `dev mode`. I want a solution for both the `dev mode` and the production environment.

The exception appears in the following line::

```
 fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~//xml"));
```

---

StackTrace:

> StackTrace    "   at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean
>   useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)\r\n   at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   String msgPath, Boolean
>   bFromProxy)\r\n   at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String
>   filename)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.SaveAs(String
>   filename)\r\n   at
>   Schedule.ScheduleForm.btn_Search_Click(Object
>   sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

---

Is the `SaveAs()` method the problem reason, or there is some thing wrong in the path? Because I tried everything, I gave full control permissions to many users, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give write access to **Network Service** on the specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

One question are you using IIS to test the app or  the build in VS server?. In the second case you need to grant permission to the user ASP.NET to the folder. Try it and see if it works

Comment: i use VS i'm in the development mode .i don't find any user with this name , i use windows 7.

Comment: I tink user appears only when the VS is running. It's been some time since i programmed in ASP but that was the solution when i had the same problem.

Comment: It also might be a windows 7 settings and you might need Admin permission, Check to see if the folder is read- only, that might be the problem

Comment: yeah ,it 's read only and when i try to change it and apply the setting , i find it's n't changed at all.

Comment: you need to change the folder permission search on google, the method  depends on what version of windows and what service pack you are using